# divergent part of a series

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to find a function that gives me the divergent part of series in any case.

The method "Series[]" does not work because `Series[42,{n,0,-1}]` gives as result 42 (which is not divergent in n)

The method "SeriesCoefficient[]" does not work because I do not know the lowest order, so that `SeriesCoefficient[1/n^2 + 1/n + 2 + n^2,{n,0,-1}]`only gives 1 (from the 1/n-term) but I loose information about the 1/n^2 term.

Is there a possibility to combine the advantages (to eliminate the disadvantages) of both approaches? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can it be that you are looking for Residue?

Comment: Not exactly ... for example: 1/n^2 + 2/n + 1 + n should give back 1/n^2 + 2/n but Residue of that function gives 1.

Comment: This might or might not be reliable: `singularPart[f_, x_, p_: 0] := 
 Expand[Normal[Series[(x - p)*f, {x, p, 1}] + O[x - p]]/(x - p)]`

Comment: Any help?: (1) `Series[expr, {n, 0, -1}] /. {s_SeriesData :> s, _ -> 0}` or (2) `#2 - (Normal[#] /. n -> Infinity) &[Series[expr, {n, 0, 0}], Series[expr, {n, 0, -1}]]`.  I don't know what you would want for functions like `Sin[1/n]`.

Answer (score 1):

You might do as follows:

```
    singPart[f_] := 
  Plus @@ ({Coefficient[f, n, #], #} & /@ 
      Range[-Exponent[f, 1/n], -1] /. {x_, y_} -> x*n^y);
```

Then if

```
f = a*n^2 + b*n + e/n^2 + c/n + d + g/n^4;

singPart[f]
```

returns

```
(*    g/n^4 + e/n^2 + c/n      *)
```

Edit: the above function works incorrectly in the case of numeric coefficients. The one below should work in the both cases:

```
    sing[f_] := Module[{g, lst, cond},
  g[{x_, y_}] := x*n^y;
  lst[z_] := {Coefficient[z, n, #], #} & /@ 
    Range[-Exponent[z, 1/n], -1];
  cond = And @@ (Map[NumberQ, lst[f], {2}] // Flatten);
  Plus @@ Map[g, If[cond, Select[lst[f], #[[1]] != 0 &], lst[f]]]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but - for exapmle - singPart[1/n^2] returns 1 - 2/n